# website shows the original source code- but google not

Tags: joomla

So this is my website https://aba-elearning.com/
when I look on the source code it shows that everything is fine.

when I ask from "google console" to test live URL I see Japanese letters.

when I ran site:aba-elearning.com in google I can see I got hacked.
So I used this free tool https://aw-snap.info/

to check my website and the result shows that there is a script somewhere inside my site that cuz that.

I checked everywhere, found some spammy php codex inside my server (Built on Joomla).
but the Japanese still there.

this is the code results from the test
https://aw-snap.info/file-viewer/?protocol=secure&ref_sel=GSP2&ua_sel=ff&chk-cache=&fs=1&tgt=fGJ8LXtse3x9bltuZy5eXW0%3D~enc

this is how google see my website: 
https://aw-snap.info/file-viewer/?protocol=secure&ref_sel=none&ua_sel=gbot2&chk-cache=&fs=0&tgt=aHR0cHM6YGB8Ynwte2x7fH1uW25nLl5dbWA%3D~enc

when I ask google to index my home page it says

[Image from google console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3VIM.png)

on top of that, I can't update the Joomla for over a year from some reason!
I have PHP knowledge and codding I looked inside the .htaccess files robots.txt 
and index.php for some fishy code, I found this:

[IMage of the code I took down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaKLX.png)

I really don't know what to do and would love for some directions!

Answer (score 0):

Your site was hacked. Someone modified your files to deliver specific content.

Here are two articles which might help you to fix the issue:

https://www.bluebridgedev.com/joomla-hacked
https://www.joomshaper.com/blog/my-joomla-site-was-hacked-what-to-do

I recommend installing Akeeba Admin Tools to prevent basic attacks.

https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/admin-tools.html

A good source for ideas to secure a site is this: https://www.bluebridgedev.com/blog/entry/how-to-secure-a-joomla-site

In general, that blog is worth a read: https://www.bluebridgedev.com/blog

For possible new security issues, I recommend subscribing to the RSS feed of:

https://developer.joomla.org/security-centre

https://vel.joomla.org/live-vel

https://www.exploit-db.com/